# How to fix TypeError for this line of code. print('You will be ' + str(int(my_age) + 1) + ' in a year.')

Tags: python-3.x

Just doing a basic code as a refresher and I keep getting the following error message: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'.

I  made sure to convert my int to str but still giving me that error.

```
print("Hello World!")
my_name = input("what is your name? ")
print('well it is nice to meet you, ' + my_name)
name_length = len(my_name)
print('The length of your name is ' + str(name_length))
my_age = print(input("How old are you? "))
my_age = int(my_age)
print('You will be ' + str(my_age + 1) + ' in a year.')
```

Comment: You are assigning the return value from `print()` to `my_age`. `print()` does not return anything so `my_age = None`.

Comment: `my_age = print(input("How old are you? "))`: `print` returns `None`

Comment: `input` prompts itself. You don't need a `print()` to do that job. And now I read that you've done this correct for inputting name.

Comment: Voting to close as typo

Comment: Thanks so much everyone!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the line `my_age = print(input("How old are you? "))` to `my_age =input("How old are you? ")`

```
print("Hello World!")
my_name = input("what is your name? ")
print('well it is nice to meet you, ' + my_name)
name_length = len(my_name)
print('The length of your name is ' + str(name_length))
my_age = input("How old are you? ")
my_age = int(my_age)
print('You will be ' + str(my_age + 1) + ' in a year.')
#Hello World!
#what is your name? Joe
#well it is nice to meet you, Joe
#The length of your name is 3
#How old are you? 5
#You will be 6 in a year.
```

Comment: Cool. Please upvote/accept if the answer helped you